# ggplot draw all elements for each group at a time

Tags: r, ggplot2

sorry for the poor header, but I was struggling to find the right wording. I hope you understand my question.

I would like to create a chart where I first draw all red elements (both lines and points) and then all all elements blue elements (both lines and points). In other words first draw everything for group==1 and then all elements for group==2. I've achieved what I want with fig2 below, but it just feels very inefficient. Is there a better way to do it?

Thank you,
Hans

```
# Load library
library("tidyverse")
library("patchwork")
# Some data
df<-tibble(x=c(1,2,5,3,4,4),y=c(1,2,4,5,3,6),group=c(1,1,1,2,2,2))
# Plot
fig1<-ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y,color=as.factor(group)))+
     geom_point(size=20)+
     geom_line(size=2)+
  theme(legend.position = "top")+labs(title="Not what I want")


# Manual
fig2<-
  ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y,color=as.factor(group)))+
  geom_point(,size=20)+ 
  geom_line(size=2)+
  geom_point(df%>%filter(group==1),mapping=aes(x=x,y=y,color=as.factor(group)),size=20, color="#F8766D")+
  geom_line(df%>%filter(group==1),mapping=aes(x=x,y=y,color=as.factor(group)),size=2, color="#F8766D")+
  geom_point(df%>%filter(group==2),mapping=aes(x=x,y=y,color=as.factor(group)),size=20, color="#00BFC4")+
  geom_line(df%>%filter(group==2),mapping=aes(x=x,y=y,color=as.factor(group)),size=2, color="#00BFC4")+
  theme(legend.position = "top")+labs(title="What I want")
fig2

fig1+fig2
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It may look silly, but I just changed the order between `line` and `point`.

```
fig2<-ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y,color=as.factor(group)))+
     geom_line(size=2)+
     geom_point(size=25)+
    theme(legend.position = "top")+labs(title="Is this what you want?")

plot(fig2)
```

another attempt:

```
df<-tibble(x=c(1,2,4,3,4,4),y=c(1,2,4,5,3,6),group=c(1,1,1,2,2,2))
df$group<-as.factor(df$group)

p1<-ggplot(df,aes(x,y))+geom_point(aes(colour=group),size=25)+geom_line(aes(colour=group),size=2)+theme(legend.position = "top")+labs(title="Is this what you want?")

plot(p1)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! 

Your solution works in the example, but not in general.  If I changed the data to:
`df<-tibble(x=c(1,2,4,3,4,4),y=c(1,2,4,5,3,6),group=c(1,1,1,2,2,2))` the last red point is above the blue line, while the red line is behind the blue line. But I would like everything in group 1 (red) to be below everything in group 2 (blue). Thanks again

Comment: @HansHenrikSievertsen sorry to hear. It's interesting because when I try `fig2+
  geom_line(data=df[df$group==1,],size=2,position=position_dodge(0.5)))`  the blue line goes under the red. But it doesn't work when I use `geom_point ` in the same way.
So I tried a different way. Check my edit. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks again. Yes that works in this example. But the problem is that it doesn't work in general. For example if the data is changed to: df<-tibble(x=c(1,2,4,3,4,4),y=c(1,2,4,5,3,6),group=c(1,1,1,2,2,2))

Given that my real dataset has thousands of  observations, I need a general solution. I think my request is in conflict with the "layer" principle, so I'll have to work with the workaround I listed above. Thanks again for your suggestions!

Comment: @Hans Henrik Sievertsen
 Thanks, please share if you find the real solution. I will ask my professor, maybe he knows the solution.